# Cython cannot find "__file__"

Tags: python, cython, os.path

I recently started using Cython, and when compiling one of my scripts, the line:

```
Y = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )))
```

seems to have issues when compiling. Now I understand it cannot find the "**file**" after it has been compiled with Cython, but I am looking for another way to find the file's local path so that it can be used to reference other files. For example, if the file was stored in `C:\Users\example\test.py`, I need something that can store that directory in a variable I can use later.

The error I receive in the command line:

`name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: If you're using Cython, you're probably using setuptools. In which case you probably want to use [Resource Manager](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) to access your data files. `setuptools`/`pkg_resources` will take care of putting them somewhere appropriate after an `install` or a `build_ext --inplace` or even something like PyInstaller bundling the whole app up as a single file, and your code doesn't have to care where that "somewhere appropriate" is.

Comment: Problem is that when loading a module in cython, it won't be in that location anymore - cython modules are converted to C extensions, compiled and then installed to python's library directory. The `.py` file is not being loaded anymore and can even be deleted at this point.

Comment: So what would you recommend? Because I need to reference .json files that are stored in the same directory as the .py files

Comment: I'd recommend not relying on the `.json` files being in any particular location at runtime, and access them with `resource_string` (or, if they're really big, `resource_stream`) instead.

Comment: But the user creates these json files, so they have to be stored and opened.

Comment: Then shouldn't they be in some location the user controls, not the source tree that your code was built from?

Comment: Ideally, you want the user to be able to, e.g., `pip install mything`, not have to download your source and `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and run it from there (or, worse, have to manually `cython` a bunch of files and copy them around), right? Where would they put the JSON files in that case?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. This code is meant to be distributed and used by an end user. It's not a pip module, it's an application.

Comment: The json files serve almost as a config for the python

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1035